# tortoisesSVN verification of commit message accidentally skip

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, pre-commit-hook

I have a TortoiseSVN install in somewhere. If I commit a changes with no message, the server should block this kind of check in.

In other world, if I commit changes with empty message, commit failed window will pop out and showing

> Error Commit failed (details follow):
>
> 1. Error Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:
> 2. Error Log message is empty
> 3. Error This error was generated by a custom hook script on the Subversion server.
> 4. Error Please contact your server administrator for help with resolving this issue.

Recently this kind of verification fail and empty message check in found in Log Message. This is properly a bug of TortoiseSVN. I would like to ask if anyone have encounter the similar situation or any suggestion to find out how to trigger the bug.

At the moment I only need to ***reproduce*** the problem to prove there is a bug in TortoiseSVN check in.

Version: TortoiseSVN 1.8.7

Comment: *This error was generated by a custom hook script on the Subversion server.* - therfore it has nothing to do with TortoiseSVN, which is a SVN client. Are you sure that: 1. Commit message is not made up of *invisible characters*? 2. Commit message was not *edited after commit*?

Comment: This is of course not at all a bug ot TortoiseSVN. Have you tried to get in contact with the maintainer of the Subversion repository? He should know why the behavior changed recently. You will not get a reasonable answer on your question, though ...

Comment: Thank for reply. The situation is embarrass, since the check in problem only happen to me...and I can't ask the maintainer to look at my specific case. Indeed I suspect I even hadn't clicked the commit button. The SVN check in code for me surprisingly...